# Witcher 3 DPS reducing

Tags: the-witcher-3

I crafted the feline silver and steel sword, don't remember how much was the DPS when I first crafted, but the DPS now seems to have reduced. I didn't change any equipment just added skill points which improve attack rating. At first I thought they were reducing because of the durability reduced, but even after I repair them the DPS don't seem to go back to initial value. And if craft the same swords again I get the current DPS for the new swords not the initial ones.

Comment: This is almost certainly confirmation bias. If you're crafting them, and the numbers are coming out the same, then you're remembering wrong.

Comment: In theory a patch (or a mod?) could rebalance some things - make monsters tougher or your sword weaker. I however have not heard about that happening in this game which suggests @Frank is correct.

Comment: Thanks, It was my fault I forgot that adrenaline points increase damage. I saw the DPS when adrenaline and other enhancers were active and thought they were the initial ones...
@Deltharis Thanks, but I didn't apply any patch or mod